# flexslider not loading "<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">"

Tags: php, flexslider

Flexslider is not working properly when the content is dynamic. I have tried it for static data, it worked. But it didn't work when the content is dynamic. The problem is it didn't load

```
<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
```

. Actually, it loads just for first tablist, it didn't load for rest of the tablists.
My code is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<?php
   foreach ($cats as $k => $cat)
   {
       $cat = (object) $cat;
       $id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $cat->category_name));
       $name = ucfirst($cat->category_name);
    ?> 
       <li role="presentation" <?php echo $k == 0 ? 'class="active":' : NULL; ?>>
            <a href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="<?php echo $id; ?>1"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
<?php
     foreach ($cats as $k => $cat)
     {
         $cat = (object) $cat;
         $id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $cat->category_name));
         $name = ucfirst($cat->category_name);

      ?> 
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php echo $k == 0 ? 'active' : NULL; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
             <div id="carousel<?php echo (7 + $k); ?>" class="flexslider">

                  <ul class="slides">
                       <li>............
                                  ..........
```

The final code after loading flexslider should look like

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="electronics">
         <div id="carousel7" class="flexslider">
              <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                <ul class="slides" style="width: 2200%; -webkit-transition: 1s; transition: 1s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                      <li style="width: 195px; float: left; display: block;">
                        <li.......
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="food">
         <div id="carousel8" class="flexslider">
              <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                <ul class="slides" style="width: 2200%; -webkit-transition: 1s; transition: 1s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                      <li style="width: 195px; float: left; display: block;">
                        <li.......
    </div>
```

But div with id carousel8 didn't load div with class flex-viewport. It only load for category electronics.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you initiate flex slider?

Comment: Just show that code.

Comment: <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

Comment: Can anyone help with that? I have the same problem when I add second slider to ASP web form page.

Comment: Solved it by initialising slider:  $('#myslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: false,
                    slideshow: false,
                    itemWidth: 190,
                    itemMargin: 10,
                    asNavFor: '#slider'
                });